# How to make DRY status-aware navbars?

Tags: php, design-patterns

For my webapp, I need to make the navbar status-aware and adapts to many combinations: whether the user is logged-in or not, its role (admin, user, guest, ...), etc.

Injecting multi-nested `if`s and function calls in HTML makes me cringe and I want to keep my code as clean and DRY as possible, for easy maintenance.

So, I thought of writing a function to automate the process. Something that would look like this :

```
public function insertButtons(array $buttons) {
    foreach($buttons as $button) {
        echo "<a href='" . $button['url'] . "'>". $button['text'] . "</a>";
    }
}
```

So that I can craft the `$buttons` in the `Controller`:

```
if($_SESSION['loggedin']) {
    $buttons[] = array('url' => '/profile', 'text' => $_SESSION['username']);
    $buttons[] = array('url' => '/logout', 'text' => 'Log out');
} else { 
    // ...
}
```

And then inject them in the HTML:

```
<div class="nav navbar">
    <!-- ... -->
    <?php insertButtons($buttons); ?>
    <!-- ... -->
</div>
```

The drawback for such a solution is, of course, the lack of flexibility.

Are there any known patterns to be used in these situations? If yes, what are they or where can I find information about them. If not, is my pseudo-code a viable solution?

Comment: You are on the right track. You've effectively created a menu factory, abstracting the menu creation data into a method. If you want to add more flexibility you can store your menu information in a database table and have query bring back the proper menu items.

Comment: Great! Though I never thought about storing UI information in a database. Is it a common practice?

Comment: Yes, it is fairly common.

Comment: Okay then! And sorry for not upvoting your comments, not enough reputation for that :/